# Jquery + Prototype in noConflict() mode, Array.prototype.indexOf broken

Tags: prototypejs, jquery

i'm trying out this jquery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stylish-select-box/

it works good but with prototype + jquery in noConflict mode
this function broke others scripts

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0); i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == obj) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    };
```

any help?

Comment: Array already has an indexOf method? why would you try to replace it? A LOT of scripts are going to rely on that expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Array already has a native indexOf method. Changing it in ways that don't produce the same results will break things. Heck, even trying to replace a native method may cause problems for methods like [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:hasOwnProperty).

If you really want that function, rename it to `myIndexOf` or something to avoid the conflict.

Comment: I think the purpose of defining `Array.prototype.indexOf` is to ensure cross-browser support; some older browsers don't support it. That said, it should only be defined when it isn't native, and it should be defined to correctly implement the spec. Regarding `hasOwnProperty`, that is actually a guard *against* this sort of monkey-patching, and it's only necessary when you change `Object.prototype` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript versions prior to 1.6 do not implement `indexOf` (i.e. IE6). However, you can easily check to see if indexOf is implemented:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
        //
    }
}
```